# Z-index of absolute positioned div nested in a fixed position div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed position div (header), that has a child div with position absolute that I would like to be on top (in terms of z-index) of everything, but I cant seem to figure out how to do this. The child div with absolute position has a height greater than the header but does not extend over.

[The fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/E8Kb2/6/).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="pgSearch" class="search-box">
                    <div class="input-results">
                        <p>this should extend over the red part</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="center">
                <p>content</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--container-->
</body>
</html>

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 89px;
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;
    background:red;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 89px;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background: green;
    z-index: 500;
}
.search-box {
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:501;
}
.search-box .input-results {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left: 1px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    z-index:9999;
    background: white;
}
```

What I want is for the white div (input-results) to be on top of everything, but instead it cuts off at the end of the header div which is fixed.

I'm losing my mind trying to figure this out.

Comment: a tip buddy instead of defining each and every element to be normalized use `* { margin:0; padding:0; }` in css

Comment: @AspiringAqib Using `*` for a selector is not recommended.

Comment: O.o @MrLister thanks thats why i was thinking why all sites do not use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have:

```
overflow-y: hidden;
```

in `.header`

That means that any content that exceeds the height of .header will be cut off. Remove that property if you don't need it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/E8Kb2/10/ there's an example of what One Trick Pony is talking about.

Comment: Exactly. Nothing to do with the z-index.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much - cant believe I missed that!

Comment: @MrLister I think `z-index` works on anything with a `position` other than `static`.

Answer (score 3):

You have the overflow-y on the .header  set to hidden. This means the white area is being copped by the height of the .header . Change this to overflow-y:visible; and that should fix your problem.

Comment: `visible` is the default value, so you'd be better off just omitting it.